# Чи має слово "знаходитися" значення "перебувати"/"розташовуватися"?

Tags: росіянізм, дієслова

Шалені дискусії починають палати навколо, коли хтось скаже: *"Біла Церква знаходиться в Київській області"* чи *"Мер Львова знаходиться у своєму кабінеті"*. В  університеті на парах з української мови викладачка запевняла (як [цей](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F/) і [цей](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/25871.html) ресурси), що замість нього потрібно вживати інші дієслова, палітра яких доволі велика (все залежить від контексту). Проте багато моїх друзів-філологів переконують: все нормально, немає нічого злочинного у використанні слова "знаходитися". То як бути?

Answer (score 3):

Навіть [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/znakhodytysja) позначає таке значення слова "знаходитися" як розмовне.

Додам також до вашого списку джерел ["Як ми говоримо"](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/znahodytysya-znajtysya-buty-perebuvaty-lezhaty).

Рекомендую прислухатися до мовознавців, а не друзів-філологів. Крім того, широка палітра інших дієслів краще й точніше описує, що саме мається на увазі.